# Is there a way to paste all the arguments in a function in one line?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I currently have this in my `.bashrc` since I use `git status` and `git diff` often. I would like to be able to read other entries that may be passed in as options like `-s` with `git diff`. How can I do that in a **function** rather than an **alias**? I only know that `$#` will give me the number of arguments passed in but how do I paste all of them after say `status` on line 48?

```
 42 # =========================================================
 43 #                         Git
 44 # =========================================================
 45 g () {
 46   case $1 in
 47     "s")
 48       git status
 49       ;;
 50     "d")
 51       git diff
 52       ;;
 53   esac
 54 }
```

Comment: git status "$@"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"$@"` will be replaced with all the arguments, correctly quoted, so after shifting to remove the sub-command shortcut:

```sh
g () {
  cmd=$1
  shift
  case "$cmd" in
    s) git status "$@" ;;
    d) git diff "$@" ;;
  esac
}
```

Instead of doing this though, I suggest using `git` aliases; to set the above up:

```
git alias s status
git alias d diff
```

or, if you don’t have `git-alias` (typically in `git-extras`),

```
git config --global alias.s status
git config --global alias.d diff
```

(you only need to do this once, the aliases are stored in `~/.gitconfig`).

Then in your shell,

```
alias g=git
```

And you’ll find `g s` etc. work as you’d expect, including with arguments.

Comment: So strings don't need to be in quotes?

Comment: Only if they have whitespace or other punctuation that the shell might interpret as a glob expansion pattern.

Comment: Thanks. Learned a lot here. I didn't even know that you could put each case in one line.

Comment: I use the (optional) leading bracket for case constants, like (s). Unbalanced brackets freak me out, possibly due to syntax highlighters having issues in the past.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt, I didn't know of git aliases. Why would you say that using them is better? Less code?

Comment: One nice thing about git aliases instead of shell functions is that the tab completion of at least bash and zsh understands them, so `g s <tab>` offers the completions for `git status`

Comment: Less code, and as Wieland says, tab completion works, and with the configuration above, the shortcuts would work with both `g` and `git`. You can also make `git` aliases which run non-`git` commands, which comes in handy in some cases. See [the aliases page in the `git` book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases).

Comment: @StephenKitt, so I can't do `git alias`. I am getting an error. But I can edit `.gitconfig`.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that, `git alias` is provided by `git-alias` in `git-extras`. I’ve added commands which will do the same thing without it.

Answer (score 0):

To exemplify

```
#!/bin/bash

g () {
    for arg in "$@"; do echo "$arg"; done
}
g 1 2 3 4
```

Running the script

```
$ ./git.sh
1
2
3
4
```